getStatusHistoryCollection missing latest comments in plugin/interceptor
I have a plugin/interceptor hooking into a Vendor webhook function.
This vendor webhook handler has an Magento\Sales\Model\Order model where they add comments through the addStatusHistoryComment function.
When my plugin function is called, I then call $order->getStatusHistoryCollection(true), to receive the comments. However the comments that are added by the Vendor webhook function are not shown, only previous comments.
I thought by passing the true boolean to the getStatusHistoryCollection the collection would 'reload' but that still doesn't include the missing comments.
Any idea how to tackle this problem?

Using the getStatusHistories instead of getStatusHistoryCollection function fixed the problem, this function includes all comments (previous + the once generated in the request).
